# Delete features from a CSV attribute table in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-table, csv

As part of a plugin project, I am coding a bunch of scripts for QGIS 2.18. My idea is to use a CSV (which is actually the result of the Distance Matrix process) as an attribute table and utilise the selectFeature, deleteFeatures already present in QGIS. Later I would use the same process but to addJoin, addField, calculateField, etc.

But on to the point, this is the code I have:

```
uri = "file:///C:/matrice_temp.csv?delimiter=%s" % (",")
table = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'Test', 'delimitedtext')
progress.setText(str(table.isValid()))  #this prints: True
progress.setText(str(table.isReadOnly())) #this prints: False
caps = table.dataProvider().capabilities()
progress.setText(str(caps)) #this prints: 131264
progress.setText(str(QgsVectorDataProvider.DeleteFeatures)) #this prints: 2
progress.setText("")

table.startEditing()
request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(u'"InputID" = "TargetID"')
request.setSubsetOfAttributes([])
request.setFlags(QgsFeatureRequest.NoGeometry)
fids = [f.id() for f in table.getFeatures(request)]
a = table.dataProvider().deleteFeatures(fids) #returns False
progress.setText(str(a)) #this prints: False
table.commitChanges()
```

I've amased a couple indications from the answers I've been looking to, if they might help you, to describe the QgsVector Layer:

- it is valid
- it is NOT read only
- it's dataprovider as some capabilities I'm unable to understand (http://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorDataProvider.html)
- it's dataprovider returns 2 for the deleteFeatures capability
- it's not shown here, but the getFeatures selects the right number of features
- and I get a False for the deleteFeatures

I have never done this in PyQGIS before (but I have with DBF tables in ArcPy) so I must be missing something big on how to treat attribute tables without geometries.

Answer (score 2):

When I check the properties of a delimited text layer in the GUI, I get

```
Capabilities of this layer
Create Spatial Index, Fast Access to Features at ID, Curved Geometries
```

... no delete features.

You might want to look into the code of the [Editable GeoCSV](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/editablegeocsv/) plugin to see how they achieve their goal.

Comment: I'll look into that thanks! it's clear that I am missing something on Attribute Table objects in pyqgis